# Screen Readers and Email

Tags: html, email, screen-readers

I am curious if there is any way to tailor my HTML so that screen readers will stop reading once it's gone through a section of an email. Right now I am having trouble with the reader reading off an element I've tabbed through. Specifically it will read the section and then start over from the beginning of the email. I am using VoiceOver and a variety of email clients, most notably Gmail, Yahoo, AOL, Hotmail.

Can I prevent this in my HTML?

Comment: This question is not explicitly [about programming](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know specifically about VO in this context, but in general it's not a developer's task to *stop* speech or Braille output, it's a user's choice to do this or not. You can prevent some elements to be output in a context (such as disabled elements which normally are not in Tab order), but you can't say "hey man, don't read this to the user!". The goal of a screen reader is to render everything a sighted user sees. So if you don't want this or that to be read by a screen reader, why does a sighted user see this content at all?
However, a developer's task is to *mark up* content in a way that would be the most comfortable for a user. If, for instance, you believe this or that part won't be too useful to a blind user, mark it with an ARIA role, such as `note` or `complementary`.